# How to generate random integers in a range

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random number in a range with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-number-in-a-range-with-java)

This feels pretty silly, but I'm not sure how to create a random integer, giving it a specific range to allow. I was trying to make it generate random numbers between -1 and 1. I tried doing that, but the `nextInt` part doesn't allow two parameters to be put within the parentheses. Am I supposed to be using something different?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Testttterrrr {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i=0;i < 10; i++)
        {
        int pepe = 0;
        pepe = rng.nextInt(1, 1-2);
        System.out.println(pepe);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Let's see how many duplicate answers we'll see

Comment: @SteveKuo 3 in 30 seconds or so, new record?

Comment: lol @ `public class Testttterrrr`. I remember holding the key down longer and longer to make a unique class name.

Comment: Hehe well I was writing a different program, but I seriously forgot how to include negative integers. So I just made a new project for simplicity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do

```
pepe = rng.nextInt(3) - 1;
```

---

`rng.nextInt(3)` returns a random element in the set *`{0, 1, 2}`* - therefore subtracting `1` returns a random element in the set *`{-1, 0, 1}`*, as desired.

---

Relevant documentation:

- [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

Answer (score 4):

Try this statement:    `int pepe = rng.nextInt(3) - 1;`

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
pepe = rng.nextInt(3) - 1;
```

To return random sequences of -1, 0, 1.

```
rng.nextInt(3)
```

returns a random number in the interval `[0..2]`. Subtract 1 and you get the interval `[-1..1]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
pepe = rng.nextInt(3) - 1;
```

the random number will be either 0, 1, or 2.  then subtracting 1 will give you either -1, 0, or 1 just like you want